# C# Parameterized Query MySQL with `in` clause

Tags: c#, mysql, parameters

I am in the process of converting several queries which were hard-coded into the application and built on the fly to parameterized queries. I'm having trouble with one particular query, which has an `in` clause:

```
UPDATE TABLE_1 SET STATUS = 4 WHERE ID IN (1, 14, 145, 43);
```

The first parameter is easy, as it's just a normal parameter:

```
MySqlCommand m = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE TABLE_1 SET STATUS = ? WHERE ID IN (?);");
m.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("", 2));
```

However, the second parameter is a list of integers representing the ids of the rows that need updating. How do I pass in a list of integers for a single parameter? Alternatively, how would you go about setting up this query so that you don't have to completely build it each and every time you call it, and can prevent SQL injection attacks?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-a-sql-in-clause (although that's SQL server instead of mysql; unlikely to be really different though)

Comment: The solution offered there was acknowledged to be incredibly slow, although it does answer the second half of my question.

Comment: There are *lots* of solutions offered there. The accepted answer isn't the most popular one.

Comment: True, but there's already been one answer here that wasn't in that question, so I guess it paid off to ask the question again.

Comment: There are non-trivial differences between Sql Server and MySql. I wouldn't trust an answer for one to apply to the other.

Comment: @AdamLassek Good point. The solution I use involves FIND_IN_SET, which is a mySQL specific function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could build up the parametrised query "on the fly" based on the (presumably) variable number of parameters, and iterate over that to pass them in.

So, something like:

```
List foo; // assuming you have a List of items, in reality, it may be a List<int> or a List<myObject> with an id property, etc.

StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder( "UPDATE TABLE_1 SET STATUS = ? WHERE ID IN ( ?")
for( int i = 1; i++; i < foo.Count )
{   // Bit naive 
    query.Append( ", ?" );
}

query.Append( " );" );

MySqlCommand m = new MySqlCommand(query.ToString());
for( int i = 1; i++; i < foo.Count )
{
    m.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter(...));
}
```

Comment: I was just thinking that. But would I gain the performance benefits of having a stored parameterized query if I did that?

Comment: Ado.Net suggests best performance is by creating a new connection, using it once and throwing it away -- at least for other SQL engines; After all, the query engine could optimise based on the query string to reuse them...

Answer (score 6):

This is not possible in MySQL.
You can create a required number of parameters and do UPDATE ... IN (?,?,?,?). This prevents injection attacks (but still requires you to rebuild the query for each parameter count).

Other way is to pass a comma-separated string and parse it.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use parameters for an IN clause.

Answer (score 3):

Old question, but in case anyone comes across this via Google, here's what I use:

```
int status = 4;  
string ids = "1,14,145,43";      

m.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", status);
m.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDs", ids);

UPDATE TABLE_1 SET STATUS = @Status WHERE FIND_IN_SET(ID, @IDs) > 0;
```

Note: FIND_IN_SET is a mySQL specific function.

Credit, where credit is due: See this question: [Add List<int> to a mysql parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681320/add-listint-to-a-mysql-parameter)

Comment: There is of course no SQL injection risk due to the parameters. I've removed that comment to avoid confusion. I believe I may have mixed up some ORM risks in the original question. There is still the index issue which could be significant depending on the size of your table.

Answer (score 0):

Loop round your list of integers and perform individual updates.

MSSQL 2008 offers table-valued parameters to avoid this issue, I'm not aware of any similar functionality in MySQL.

Comment: That would be incredibly inefficient, considering that this query could, in some cases, have thousands of items in the IN clause.

Comment: Isn't there a limit to how many items you can have in an IN clause?

Answer (score 0):

Since MySQL 4.0 you can use **FIND_IN_SET** function to create parametrized SQL with 'in clause'.

Your code:

```
UPDATE TABLE_1 SET STATUS = 4 WHERE ID IN (1, 14, 145, 43);
```

Changed to use FIND_IN_SET:

```
UPDATE TABLE_1 SET STATUS = 4 WHERE FIND_IN_SET(ID, 1, 14, 145, 43);
```

Finally you can use variables to parametrize your query:

```
var s = "UPDATE TABLE_1 SET STATUS = 4 WHERE FIND_IN_SET(ID, ?)";
var params = "1, 14, 145, 43";

dataSource.Execute(s, params);
```

See the [W3Schools reference](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_find_in_set.asp) and the [MySQL Tutorial](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-find_in_set/)

Since **FIND_IN_SET** is a MySQL function **it works with every language not just C#**.

Answer (score 0):

I recently found out how slow find_in_set is, so I try to avoid it.  I also try to avoid constructing my sql to help prevent injection attacks.  I've found you can achieve what's required and use a parameterised query at the same time.

```
int[] ids = new int[] { 1, 2, 3};

command.CommandText = @"
  SET @temp = @ids;
  SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE table_name_id IN @temp;
";

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("ids", string.Join(",", ids));
```

Old question, but it confirmed my suspicion and I came up with this workaround.

Comment: ids is going to be treated as a string by mysql, so only the first occurence of id in the string will be found

Answer (score -1):

i'd suggest creating a function (assuming that mysql supports user defined functions) to break the parameter apart to return a table.