# Add List<int> to a mysql parameter

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, mysql-connector, mysql-parameter

I have this question about the MySqlParameter from the .NET connector.

I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (@parameter)
```

And the MySqlParameter is:

```
intArray = new List<int>(){1,2,3,4};

...connection.Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("parameter", intArray);
```

This is possible?
Is possible to pass an array of int to a single MySqlParameter?
The other solution will be convert the array of int to a string such like "1,2,3,4", but this, when i pass it to the MySqlParameter and this is recognized as a string, it puts in the sql query like "1\,2\,3\,4" and this do not return the expected values.

@ UPDATE: Seems like the mysql connector team should work a little bit harder.

Comment: It's not just MySQL. As far as I know, this isn't supported in MSSQL either, nor is it part of the T-SQL specification.

Comment: NHibernate and other ORMs give the impression of supporting this but under the hood they are doing string concatenation (with or without parameters)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> when i pass it to the MySqlParameter and this is recognized as a string, it puts in the sql query like "1\,2\,3\,4" and this do not return the expected values.

I ran into this last night. I found that FIND_IN_SET works here:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id, @parameter) != 0
...
intArray = new List<int>(){1,2,3,4};
conn.Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("parameter", string.Join(",", intArray));
```

Apparently this has some length limitations (I found your post looking for an alternate solution), but this may work for you.

Comment: The previous comment is misleading... Mud is using a parameterized query to achive the goal.  Parameterized queries are literally what you use to prevent sql injection in strings without having to manually scrub the contents of the string.  This is a great example of achieving the goal.

Comment: @NickHanshaw You are of course correct. I believe I may have mixed this up with a comment on the original question about ORMs and string concatenation. In any case, I'm deleting my comment to avoid any confusion. Good catch, thanks. Indexes are still an issue, but that might be okay depending on the table.

Answer (score 6):

Parameters don't work with IN. I have always embedded such things as a string in the query itself. While that is generally considered bad form because SQL injection, if you are constructing the query from a strongly typed numeric list, then there should be no possibility of any external input corrupting it in a meaningful way.

Comment: Maybe i explained wrong.. when i said "convert the array to string and pass it" i dont mean "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN(" + strings + ")"...

Comment: I know, and I'm saying it's not possible to do it the way you want.

Answer (score 3):

you are going to have to iterate over your array and create the list yourself

```
// no parameters
var sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i=0;i<intArray.Length;i++)
{
    sb.Append(intArray[i] + ",");// no SQL injection they are numbers
}
if (sb.Length>0) {sb.Length-=1;}
string sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (" + sb.ToString() + ")";
```

UPDATE: Having thought more about this I'll go back to my original answer (below) which is to use parameters. Optimisations of built queries and whatever the database engine can muster are up to you.

```
// no parameters
var sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i=0;i<intArray.Length;i++)
{
    sb.AppendFormat("p{0},", i);// no SQL injection they are numbers
    connection.Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("p"+i, intArray[i]);
}
if (sb.Length>0) {sb.Length-=1;}
string sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (" + sb.ToString() + ")";
```

Comment: that whole loop and check can be replaced with `string.Join(",", intArray)`

Comment: well, yes if you wanted short readable code :-) rather than in my case forgotten about that method

Comment: smells of sql injection. Even if you're using a relatively "safe" type in like an int sequence, imo it's a bad habit.

Comment: I wasn't the down voter btw - while longer than needed this is still an answer that applies to the question

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn, bad habit yes, however if you are making an active design decision then it is a solid solution (if longer than required as pointed out)

Comment: "smells of sql injection" i agree, and i dislike this, but it's also the only way to solve the problem in some situations without doing something silly like iterating "id=@parm_x.." over and over. There is absolutely no risk when using strongly typed numeric data. The key to avoiding problems like sql injection isn't just blind faith in doing things a certain way - it's also knowing what you are doing.

Comment: The thing as i said... i am currently using the string s = string.Join(",", intArray) but when i pass command.Parameter.AddWithValue("parameter", s) in the query, mysql connector pass the parameter like "1\,2\,3" and the select query doesn't work as the expected.

Comment: a string containg a comma delimited list of numbers cannot be the value for a parameter in any SQL driver I know. Note in my sample I am setting *the whole* SQL value, there are no parameters. As discussed elsewhere you cannot pass and array in with the SQL. I will update my answer with more detail

Answer (score 3):

You have a few options here (in order of preference):

1. Use a database that supports [table valued parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx).  This is the *only* way to get the exact syntax you want.
2. The data has to come from somewhere: either your database, user action, or machine-generated source.

   - If the data is already in your database, use a subquery instead.
   - For other machine generated data, use BULK INSERT, SqlBulkCopy, or your database's preferred bulk import tools.
   - If it's created by the user, add it to a separate table *on each individual user action*, and then use a sub query.

     An example of this is a shopping cart.  A user might select several items to purchase.  Rather than keep these in the app and need to add all the items to an order in one go when they check out, add each item to a table in the db as the user selects or changes it.
3. Have an sql user defined function that unpacks a string parameter into a table and returns that table as a set you can use with an IN() expression.  See the linked article below for more detailed information on how this works.
4. Build a string list or parameter list dynamically on the client (as shown in other answers). Note that this is my *least* preferred option, as the code it creates tends to be crazy-vulnerable to sql injection issues.

The definitive (and I mean **definitive**) work on the subject is here:

http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html

The article long, but in a good way.  The author is a sql server expert, but the concepts on the whole apply to MySQL as well.

Answer (score 1):

As I know you cannot provide any array as a parameter to prepared statement. IN() doesn't support parameters as an array.

Comment: You can do the IN thing... do the "where id IN (1,2,3,4)" is the same of "where id = 1 or id = 2 or id = 3 or id = 4", at least this works for me :)

Comment: @user710422 AS I can see in your example there is no parameters to bind. And we talk about them only.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution might be creating a stored procedure, which creates a temporary table which you can then use later for the IN-Clause:

First you create the stored procedure in for example the MySQL Workbench:

```mysql
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS CreateCustomStringSplitTable;

DELIMITER $$

-- Creates a table with entries splitted by the delimiter
CREATE PROCEDURE CreateCustomStringSplitTable
(
    IN liste LONGTEXT,
    IN delim CHAR(1)
)



BEGIN

    Declare DelimCount bigint;
    Declare CurrentDelimIndex int;
    Declare OldDelimIndex int;
    
    drop temporary table if exists CustomStringSplitTable;
    create temporary table CustomStringSplitTable( splittedString VARCHAR(255) );
    
    Set liste = CONCAT(liste, delim),
    DelimCount = LENGTH(liste) - LENGTH(REPLACE(liste, delim, '')),
    CurrentDelimIndex = 0,
    OldDelimIndex = 0;
    
    WHILE DelimCount > 0 DO
    
        Set CurrentDelimIndex = LOCATE(delim, liste, CurrentDelimIndex + 1);
        
        -- Without the +1 the subtring would start at the DelimiterIndex and take the delimiter into the result. -1 at the end, because you need to remove a character or else the next delimiter is taken into the result
        Insert into CustomStringSplitTable Select Substring(Liste, OldDelimIndex +1, CurrentDelimIndex - OldDelimIndex -1);
        
        Set OldDelimIndex = CurrentDelimIndex,
        DelimCount = DelimCount - 1;
    
    END WHILE;

END $$
```

Then you can use it in your C# code like:

```cs
string delimiter = ",";
stringArray = string.Join(delimiter, new List<int>(){1,2,3,4});

string query = @"

CALL CreateCustomStringSplitTable
(
    @array, 
    @delimiter
);

SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ((select * from CustomStringSplitTable))
";

// ...

 using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection)) 
            {
                command .Parameters.Add("@delimiter", MySqlDbType.String);
                command .Parameters["@delimiter"].Value = delimiter;

                command .Parameters.Add("@array", MySqlDbType.String);
                command .Parameters["@array"].Value = stringArray;

                // ...
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way you can add them like that, but perhaps you could iterate through the list and generate the query dynamically.

For example:

```
var intArray = new List<int>(){1,2,3,4};
if (intArray.Count > 0) {
    var query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (";
    for (int i = 0; i < intArray.Count; i++) {
        //Append the parameter to the query
        //Note: I'm not sure if mysql uses "@" but you can replace this if needed
        query += "@num" + i + ",";
        //Add the value to the parameters collection
        ...connection.Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("num" + i, intArray[i]);
    }
    //Remove the last comma and add the closing bracket
    query = query.Substring(0, query.Length - 1) + ");";
    //Execute the query here
}
```

This way, you could even use a differently typed list and still reap the benefits of parameterized queries. However, I don't know if there would be performance issues with larger lists but I suspect that would be the case.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work well for huge lists, but it is the **only** thing I have found that works if you *have* to pass a list in as a parameter.

Instead of

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (@parameter)
```

You have to do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE INSTR(','+@parameter+',', ','+CAST(the_column AS CHAR) + ',')
```

Then you can pass in your list with `string.Join(",", intArray)`

It's a kludge, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from Mud only works for the first int in the parameter list. This means '2,1,3,4' won't work if id is 1 for example.

See [FIND_IN_SET() vs IN()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155873/find-in-set-vs-in) .

No comment possible by now but also see answer from Matt Ellen.
Would edit his answer but can't. INSTR doesn't seem to work in a WHERE case with more than one id (returns only on result).

But replacing `INSTR` with `LOCATE` make his solution work (with `String.Join(",", intArray)` as parameter added) ... UP VOTE from me:

```
LOCATE(CONCAT(',' , CAST(id AS CHAR) , ',') , CONCAT(',' , CAST(@paramter AS CHAR) , ',')) <> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [Richard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/429949/richard-marskell-drackir) answer, I came up with a similar approach avoiding the SQL Injection:

```
private MySqlCommand GetCommandWithIn(string sql, string sqlParam, ICollection<string> list)
{
    var command = new MySqlCommand(string.Empty, connection);
    var i = 0;
    var parameters = new List<string>(list.Count);

    foreach (var element in list)
    {
        var parameter = $"p{i++}";
        parameters.Add($"@{parameter}");
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameter, element);
    }

    command.CommandText = sql.Replace(sqlParam, string.Join(',', parameters));

    return command;
}
```

And you can call it with:

```
var types = new List<string> { "Type1", "Type2" };
var sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Type IN (@Type)"
using var command = GetCommandWithIn(sql, "@Type", types);
```

Remember to check for empty list in order to avoid the `IN ()`.