# How do you use the MySql IN clause

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to figure out how to use the MySql In cluse with ASP.NET C#. Here is my code

```
var WebSites = string.Join(",", wsl.Select(x => "'" + x.DomainUrl + "'").ToArray());
string q = "select Id, Url, Title, Date, ImageUrl from post where WebSiteUrl IN (@Url)";
```

When I dont use parameters this code works. When I include parameters I get no results from the query.

Here is my code for parameters

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Urls", MySqlDbType.Text).Value = WebSites;
```

here is whole code

```
 public static IList<Post> FindPostsByWebSiteList(IEnumerable<WebSite> wsl)
 {
        var pl = new List<Post>();
        var WebSites = string.Join(",", wsl.Select(x => "'" + x.DomainUrl + "'").ToArray());
        string q = "select Id, Url, Title, Date, ImageUrl from post where WebSiteUrl IN (@Urls)";

        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySqlConnectionString"].ToString()))
        {
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(q, con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Urls", MySqlDbType.Text).Value = WebSites;
                con.Open();

                var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var p = new Post();
                    p.Id = reader.GetInt32("Id");
                    p.Url = reader.GetString("Url");
                    p.Title = reader.GetString("Title");
                    p.Date = reader.GetDateTime("Date");
                    p.ImageUrl = reader.GetString("ImageUrl");
                    pl.Add(p);
                }
                return pl;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That happens because you bind all the urls in a single string.

Comment: I am not familiar with binding parameters in C#, but are you sure you can bind in this manner?  Usually you will bind an actual parameter of the query.  What you are doing is binding part of the query.  The `IN` clause is expecting a comma-separated list.  You are giving it a single variable instead, whose value contains the text of a comma-separated list.  I'd imagine this will cause problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the answer. Here it is

```
    public static IList<Post> FindPostsByWebSiteList(string[] urls)
    {
        var pl = new List<Post>();
        var urlArray = urls.Select((x,y) => "@url" + y.ToString()).ToArray();
        var urlsJoined = string.Join(",", urlArray);
        string q = string.Format("select Id, Url, Title, Date, ImageUrl from post where WebSiteUrl IN ({0})", urlsJoined);

        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySqlConnectionString"].ToString()))
        {
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(q, con))
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < urlArray.Length; x++)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(urlArray[x], MySqlDbType.Text).Value = urls[x];
                }

                con.Open();

                var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var p = new Post();
                    p.Id = reader.GetInt32("Id");
                    p.Url = reader.GetString("Url");
                    p.Title = reader.GetString("Title");
                    p.Date = reader.GetDateTime("Date");
                    p.ImageUrl = reader.GetString("ImageUrl");
                    pl.Add(p);
                }
                return pl;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have referenced @Url instead of @Urls

maybe just a typo in your question though

Comment: Hmmm..I have corrected the mistake but its still not returning any results

Comment: The problem you have is that your query becomes IN ( "..." ) the entire list of urls gets encoded as a string. You might need to compose that part of the query manually using `MySqlHelper.EscapeString` would need to be tested though

Answer (score 0):

The IN statement should expect an Array of strings, and you are passing a single string

Your final SQL is looking like this:

```
select Id, Url, Title, Date, ImageUrl from post where WebSiteUrl IN ('url1,url2,url3')
```

Instead of

```
select Id, Url, Title, Date, ImageUrl from post where WebSiteUrl IN ('url1', 'url2', 'url3')
```

Check this question:

[Add List<int> to a mysql parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681320/add-listint-to-a-mysql-parameter)