# How do i include several search criteria into a SQL Command using C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

The search criteria comes from a CheckBox-List populated by database values [1,2,3,4,5,6...].

I want to be able to retrieve the selected checkbox values and include it into the `WHERE` criteria of my SQL Command before executing it.

[Click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHCbK.png)

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string checkedSkills = "";

        //Store The checked values from chkBoxSkillset into a List.
        List<ListItem> selected = new List<ListItem>();
        foreach (ListItem item in chkBoxSkillset.Items)
            if (item.Selected)
                selected.Add(item);

        string checkedSkills = "SELECT DISTINCT Student.*FROM Student" +
            " INNER JOIN StudentSkillSet ON Student.StudentID = 
           StudentSkillSet.StudentID WHERE StudentSkillSet.SkillSetID IN (" 
           + checkedSkills; 

        foreach (ListItem skill in selected)
        {   
            checkedSkills+=Convert.ToString
            (selected[Convert.ToInt16(skill)] + ",");
        }

        checkedSkills += ")";

    }
```

Do i use cmd.Parameters or QueryString? How should i format it so it works?

Comment: Although [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterize-an-sql-in-clause) is for SQL server, it's conceptually similar and might help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you use the MySql IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804657/how-do-you-use-the-mysql-in-clause)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use `String.Format()` and `String.Join()` for example you could write down your query in this manner

```
string query = SELECT DISTINCT Student.* FROM Student 
INNER JOIN StudentSkillSet ON Student.StudentID = 
StudentSkillSet.StudentID WHERE StudentSkillSet.SkillSetID IN ({0})
```

Then since you are getting a `List<ListItem>` you could use LINQ to get the desired values, in your case

> `String.Join(", ", select.Select(item => item).Where(x => x.Selected == true).ToList())` which will concatenate all the values in your list in this manner "item1, item2, item3..."

Then you can use the `String.Format(query, String.Join(", ", select.Select(item => item).Where(x =>x.Selected == true).ToList())` which will automatically create your query, it is more concise and less steps than creating several `foreach` loops.