# How can I pass several integer values within one sql parameter?

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

I've got a stored procedure with the following criteria:

```
WHERE (Transaction_tbl.dtime BETWEEN @fromDate AND @toDate)   
  AND (Location_tbl.Locid IN (@locations))
```

I've got a ListBox which populates the `@locations` parameter (an integer), and two DateTimePicker controls for the `@fromDate` and `@toDate`.

I took my listbox value like this:

```
cnt = LSTlocations.SelectedItems.Count
        Dim list As New List(Of Integer)
        Dim locid As Integer
        If cnt > 0 Then
            For i = 0 To cnt - 1
                Dim locationanme As String = LSTlocations.SelectedItems(i).ToString
                locid = RecordID("Locid", "Location_tbl", "LocName", locationanme)
                list.Add(locid)
            Next
        End If
```

> i want to pass this list item value to my stored procedure...how i can
>   do this?

```
cmd23.Parameters.Add("@startDate", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, ParameterDirection.Input).Value= startdate
cmd23.Parameters.Add("@endDate", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = enddate
cmd23.Parameters.Add("@locations", SqlDbType.Int) ' <= ???
```

How can this code be modified to pass several integer identifiers as the `@locations` parameter so that I may select several items in my listbox?

Comment: Parameters are for single values so when using parameters you would need to create as much parameters as there are in the in the List.

Comment: Have you checked this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681320/add-listint-to-a-mysql-parameter

Comment: Sir..I am Using VB.net

Comment: i am new in vb.net..can u pleas show how i can do same in vb.net

Comment: That would only help if you are also using mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Change your locations parameter to a string.

SELECT items
INTO #locations 
FROM dbo.split(@locations,',')

You can find the split function here: [Split string by comma in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999631/split-string-by-comma-in-sql-server-2008)

You'll have to change your query to join with the #locations temporary table.

then from your VB pass in a comma delmited string of all the selected items from LSTlocations

something like this:

[String].Join(", ", LSTlocations.Items.Cast(Of ListItem)().Where(Function(i) i.Selected).[Select](Function(i) i.Value).ToArray())

Comment: actulayy locid is integer...so how i can pass string

Comment: you said to locations parameter to change string...actulally i have to pass ther integer value

Comment: how i can change my location parameter..? like u suggested

Comment: change it to a string like the lines above it. But that's one of a number of changes you need to make. You also need to change the SP and to get all the selected items from the listbox into a string. I've provided details of what to do at every stage. I'm assuming you have a basic level of competence to do these things.