# How to pass string to where clause - mySQL

Tags: c#, mysql

I hope someone could help.

From a C# app, I need to get some data from **mySQL** db.
There is no procedure, so unfortunately I have to write the query inside the code...

I have a list of ids (guid), which I am sending through postman

```
{
   "meetingIds":[
      "9a4059c9-8c41-0afp-245e-9b9147bd5549",
      "b90oz505-9adb-ca9c-7791-5b9133bb7a1c",
      "9ghfc65b-1abb-88u6-8584-5e8p8af61050"
   ]
}
```

afer received into the app, I am adding the single quote to each of them

```
var singleQuote = "";
string stringOfIds = string.Join(", ", request.meetingIds.Select(x => singleQuote + x + singleQuote));
```

so I am getting a string which looks like this:

```
'9a4059c9-8c41-0afp-245e-9b9147bd5549', 'b90oz505-9adb-ca9c-7791-5b9133bb7a1c', '9ghfc65b-1abb-88u6-8584-5e8p8af61050'
```

and I am passing that to a query as string (meetingIds), but I am getting no results... if I pass just one id, it works fine.

This is the part of the query

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(
@"select     u.user_id          as userId,
             u.first_name       as firstName,
             u.last_name        as lastName,
             u.date_inserted    as dateModified, 
             u.campaign         as campaignId, 
             u.status           as status, 
             from meetings u
             where m.id in (@meetingIds);", conn);

             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@meetingIds", meetingIds);
```

I know about the danger of SQL injection, but I dont see any other way to do this... and even this one is not working...

I am open for all suggestions, thank you.

Comment: You could use table-valued parameters (if MySQL supports these), but another approach would be to ensure each parses to a GUID before passing it to SQL (and call `.ToString()` on that GUID), which would protect against SQL injection.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama probably that's the best for mysql (not really sure). Obviously OP looked up regular SQL approach https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterize-an-sql-in-clause and figured that it did not work either...

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama, my first approach was exactly using the data table, but unfortunately mySQL dont support it...

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with MySQL to know if there's a better solution for it there. Hopefully someone who is more acquainted with it can answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you run into the same issue as: [Add List<int> to a mysql parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681320/add-listint-to-a-mysql-parameter). The answer using `FIND_IN_SET` function should solve your problem as well. Hope it helps.

Comment: yes, the same problem, and I have managed to get the results, by constructing the query, my where looks like this now: where m.id in (" + meetingIds+ ");", conn); and by @ProgrammingLlama suggestion, I am checking does string parse to guid, so there is no fear about the sql injection :) thanks guys