# Unable to execute MySQL query using the IN clause

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, execute

I am trying to perform a query that reads a list of projects from a database where the project's state is within a given list. I have written this query (using C#, also):

```
string statesList = "(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)"; // This is built inside a function, it could include any or all of these values, e.g. (1, 3, 4);

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT p.Name, p.State_Id FROM Projects p
    WHERE p.State_Id IN @states";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@states", statesList);
```

When I run this query, I am given this error:

```
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)'' at line 1".
```

I'm stumped. Can anyone see what I'm missing?

Comment: You can't use an parameter for the list of the IN() operator. You can use a loop to get those parameters (you need 5 in your example). Don't forget your parentheses around this list too.

Comment: You can't use Parameters for `IN` values. You have two options. Either concatenated your string `statesList` with your `CommandText` or See [this Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/337792/961113) for manually adding parameters for each value.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterize-a-sql-in-clause

Comment: Oh, I never knew that. What do you think would be the best way to write a loop like that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Parameterized Query MySQL with \`in\` clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650455/c-sharp-parameterized-query-mysql-with-in-clause)

Comment: I had no idea the parameters were the issue. It didn't even occur to me. Sorry for duplicate.

Comment: Hi what about Python? Can be parameterize IN clause with Python code? I have a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67925365/parameterize-an-mysql-in-clause-in-python-code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the misconception that using parameterized queries works the same as a string replacement. The resulting query is *not*

```
SELECT p.Name, p.State_Id FROM Projects p WHERE p.State_Id IN (1,2,3,4,5)
```

You can not use a parameterized query the way you do here.

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea that paramaters weren't allowed for the in clause. All I did was concatenate the command text: `cmd.CommandText = "SELECT p.Name, p.State_Id FROM projects p WHERE p.State_Id IN "; cmd.CommandText += statesList;` I'll be back in 10 minutes to accept this.

Answer (score 1):

Your resulting query is:

```
SELECT p.Name, p.State_Id
FROM Projects p
WHERE p.State_Id IN ('1, 2, 3, 4, 5');
```

Which is the same as:

```
WHERE p.State_Id = '1, 2, 3, 4, 5' <-- a single string value
```

If you don't care about indexes, you can do what you want as:

```
SELECT p.Name, p.State_Id
FROM Projects p
WHERE find_in_set(p.State_Id, @states) > 0
```

Note:  you should remove the spaces after the commas for this.

Alternatively, do a direct substitution of the list into the string.  Unfortunately, I don't think there is a better, convenient solution.

Comment: Thanks! Indexes is important, because I want a query that can select any number of project states based on command line parameters. The first one works fine, I already have a function that builds the string. The error was in using a paramatized value for the list.