# Mysql Parametrized query with IN command in c#?

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a mysql query with a "WHERE id_field IN(....)"

How can i set the parameters inside the "IN(...)" like IN(@param) using `SqlParameter`? Is this possible?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650455/c-sharp-parameterized-query-mysql-with-in-clause

Comment: Ouch... sorry, i didn't saw this question (i have searched before making this question.. sorry).